# Connection Failed=>ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null} Android Wear

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os

I am trying to get GPS coordinates from Android wear watch (moto 360 sport). As a first step towards it, I need to connect to GoogleApiClient. Below is the code for the same. But the connection to GoogleApiClient is always failing with the error message.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setAmbientEnabled();

        mContainerView = (BoxInsetLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        mClockView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clock);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
```

Connection Failed=>ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171361/android-wear-error-connectionresultstatuscode-service-version-update-required). The accepted answer did not work for me. The google play services version of my mobile phone is 9.4.52(440-127739847) and the google play services in my watch is 8.7.01(2590918-534). I tapped on this version in my watch. But it checked for updates did not show up anything (Do I need wifi in my watch to check for updates and install the updates?). Since the accepted answer did not work, I moved on to the last answer of that thread. So I downloaded 8.7.01 (2590918-440) (though the last 3 numbers doesn't match). when I tried to install this apk in my mobile, I got Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]
 as my version of play services in my mobile is higher than that of watch. How should I proceed with this issue?

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Android Wear watches (about 10%, according to polls) got stuck at lower Play Services versions. If your watch is one of them, neither pressing the version number, **nor anything else** will make it update. Google are aware of the issue (see [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/114200575031804596117/posts/cmio8iB6o72) and [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AppGlobe/posts/R1Qujo9T3uz)), and likely to find a solution soon (see [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/114200575031804596117/posts/PcS3ik7mCij)). Temporarily they advise not to use Play Sevices 9.x, until the problem is resolved.

Pay attention to the fact, that the wearable apk using 9.x, wrapped into the Application-release.apk **will not be deployed on watches stuck at 8.x**. It'll be waiting forever for the Play Services to update.

E.g. use:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0"
```

instead of

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0"
```

in your build.gradle on both Application and Wearable sides.

It doesn't matter that your phone runs a higher version.

Comment: my phone has play services 12.5 version while the watch has 9.4.52 version
still i'm not able to connect

Comment: Even my old Sony Smartwatch 3 runs 12.5.29 at the moment. You should try to update. Clicking the version number triggers attempt do download the latest version. Did you try?